# Анчутка и ерпёска (ерпёстка)

Tags: фольклор, значение-слов

Моя прабабушка в своем лексиконе использовала 2 "ругательства": анчутка и ерпёска (ерпёстка). Оба слова употреблялись в отношении хулиганистых детей. Если с анчуткой все более-менее ясно, то возникает вопрос: кто такой "ерпёска" или "ерпёстка"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У М. Фасмера нашла "ерпеси́ть" - "болтать, хвастать, врать; беспокоиться, тревожиться", олонецк. (Кулик.). Возм., к ерепе́ниться.
Значит, ерпёстка - болтун, хвастунишка, враль. Анчутка - по славянской мифологии маленький злой дух, одно из названий черта (помесь черта и утки).